# Firefox Float issue

Tags: css, firefox, css-float

I have checked in multiple versions of Firefox and still get a issue with the contact form on this page floating.  [Here is my problem page](http://www.ab-mobile-apps.com/broncobuilders/contest/)

It works and looks just fine in IE, Safari and Chrome.  This issue is with firefox and I have spent an few hours trying to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, the correct page is http://www.ab-mobile-apps.com/broncobuilders/contest/

Comment: What exactly is wrong with it? Can you post some pictures to compare?

Comment: So please explain this "issue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `float:left`  for `<table width="487" border="1">`

Answer (score 0):

It seems adding **float:left** to the table will do the fix.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging Firefox issue, I recommend using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) if you're not already.

Have fun!